# No page's title background picture on iOS

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using The7 theme for the website I've created in Wordpress. Everything works well except that the page's title background picture is not showing up on iOS. Any advices how to fix it?

Comment: We need more information. Do you have any specific code that you think might be causing this issue? Is it working on Android mobile devices?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know CSS almost at all so I don't exactly know where to look for the root cause in my website's editor on WP. It works well on Android mobile devices.

Comment: I’m not sure we can help you much here if we don’t know what your website looks like or what the code looks like. If you go to Appearance > Editor you can access your code.

Comment: I don't recommend you go to the editor if you don't know any code. Can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: And what do you mean by page's title background picture?! Can you show us screenshots of it visible and hidden?

Comment: uni-job.pl and I mean the background picture which is behind the title of particular page like for example: "welcome" or "about us"